# Zindex on before causing hover issues on sidebar menu

Tags: css, hover, z-index

I have a sidebar menu that has icons. The menu text should show up only when the icons are hovered. However, this is not working perfectly because of Zindex issues on before element. As shown in the image below, hovering the red zone should not show the sidebar menu but it is.

IMAGE SHOWING THE ISSUE ->>> https://symu.co/zwfqpj

Here is a live demo of the issue- http://healthsphere.starazure.com.  I cannot even click on the logo because the before element of the sidebar which is 210 pixels wide takes over.

My boss wants me to fix this and I am not able to. Thanks for your help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your menu is too large https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CkJc.png . Try use this CSS for change menu width.

```
.uk-notouch .tm-sidebar-fixed .tm-sidebar{width:50px; overflow:hidden;}
.uk-notouch .tm-sidebar-fixed .tm-sidebar.uk-open-menu{width:210px; overflow:auto;}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That almost did the trick but broke a few things. These were working before  - 1) [link](https://symu.co/stddcq)       2) [link](https://symu.co/xpacpz)
       3)  [link](https://symu.co/ymgfyj)